# Converting an unmanaged GUID to a managed Guid^

Tags: casting, c++-cli

I'm brand new to C++/CLI and I am attempting to convert a native C++ GUID to my C++/CLI Guid^.  When attempting my conversion:

```
BlockInfo^ blockInfo = gcnew BlockInfo();
blockInfo->BlockFilterGuid = ba.BlockAllFilter.subLayerKey;
```

...I recieve the following error:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'GUID' to 'System::Guid ^'

I understand that the root source of my problem is that am trying to convert from an unmanaged to a managed type, but I'm not proficent enough in either C++ or C++/CLI to know how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A native `GUID` is defined:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
    DWORD Data1;
    WORD  Data2;
    WORD  Data3;
    BYTE  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

You need to allocate a `System::Guid` and construct it properly using the data in the native `GUID`.

```
System::Guid ^FromNativeGUID(const GUID &g)
{
    return gcnew System::Guid(g.Data1, g.Data2, g.Data3, g.Data4[0], g.Data4[1], g.Data4[2],
                        g.Data4[3], g.Data4[4], g.Data4[5], g.Data4[6], g.Data4[7]);
}
```

Comment: System::Guid is a value type. Your function works great, but the return type should really be System::Guid (instead of System::Guid^) and the gcnew should be dropped.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is fine, but this really should be enough:

```
Guid FromNativeGUID(const GUID &guid)
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<Guid *>(const_cast<GUID *>(&guid));
}
```